# Problema para usar IP do usuário ao invés do servidor no CURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou usando uma função CURL dessa forma, para ler o conteúdo do `curl` com IP do usuário e não do servidor:

```
function curl($url) {
$curl = curl_init($url) or die("Erro, o CURL não está habilitado.");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Forwarded-For: ' . $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$string = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $string;
}
```

Porém, não está funcionando.
Acaba usando o IP do servidor mesmo utilizando o  `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]`, já que o site está no Cloudflare.

É possível corrigir isso?

Answer (score 0):

Não há como corrigir. Considerando que o cURL é executado no servidor, portanto a requisição terá o IP do servidor.

O que você é quer, basicamente: forjar um IP usando TCP.

---

Não há como você usar o IP do cliente. Definir o `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-IP` ou `X-Real-IP` (...) não irá mudar nada, isso é apenas um cabeçalho qualquer. Este cabeçalho DEVE ser ignorado pelo site, nenhum site deve acreditar que o seu IP é um desses. Você só conseguirá "forjar o IP" se o seu alvo acreditar nesses cabeçalhos, o que é um erro dele, unicamente.

Forjar um IP (usando TCP) é extremamente complicado, impossível em casos gerais, devido ao handshake. O cURL, por si, não oferece nada que possa te ajudar nisso.